# Prevent drawing @2x in HTML5 Canvas on iPad 3

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, canvas

I've written a game for the HTML5 canvas, but unfortunately the performance on it is less than ideal on the iPad 3. I'm unsure if this issue is caused by the retina display of the iPad, but suspect it may be. Is there a way to prevent the iPad from drawing @2x in the canvas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.5,initial-scale=0.5">
```

scale is 0.5 because window.devicePixelRatio = 2 on retina displays (scale = 1.0/2)